Как удалить все строки из матрицы содержащие -10
Вот у меня есть код
import numpy as np

mtrx = np.random.randint(-10, high = 10, size = (8,8))

print(mtrx)


Код вы напишете сами, поскольку это учебное задание. Я дам вам план:

Сравниваем всю матрицу (т.е. каждый элемент матрицы) с -10 на равенство
Используем функцию any с указанием нужной оси, чтобы найти строки, для которых условие выше выполняется хотя бы для одного элемента
Используем отрицание ~ чтобы инвертировать условие
Берём из матрицы строки, используя логическую маску, которую мы выше сформировали


Можно найти все номера строк, где есть -10 np.where(np.any(mtrx == -10, axis=1)), а потом все эти строки удалить np.delete(mtrx, Все_Эти_строки, axis=0)
